Spark: No implicits found for parameter evidence
I have the following Spark code on Scala:
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
       val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()
       import spark.implicits._

    val scheme = new StructType()
        .add(new StructField("state_id", IntegerType, true))
        .add(new StructField("state", StringType, true))
         .add(new StructField("recommendation", StringType, true))

  val statesDf: DataFrame = spark.read
        .format("jdbc")
        .schema(scheme)
        .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
        .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres")
        .option("dbtable", "public.states")
        .option("user", "postgres")
        .option("password", "postgres")
        .load()

   statesDf.map(r => Row(r.getInt(0) * 2)).show()

  }

And I receive the error near "map"-function:
 No implicits found for parameter evidence$6: Encoder[Row]  

I expected "import spark.implicits._" was enough for prevent this problem, but I was wrong

Row encoders can be used by creating an implicit via the Encoders.row function.  Prefer using sql functions with named parameters in further selects (with as many column expressions as possible in each select), it's far faster than using map whether Row or another Encoder type.

The map function is intended to be used with (typed) datasets.
You could use
val mapped1: Dataset[Int] = statesDf.map(r => r.getInt(0) * 2)

or
case class MyClass(id: Integer)
val mapped2: Dataset[MyClass] = statesDf.map(r => MyClass(r.getInt((0)*2)))

The implicit encoders work mostly for primitives, their sequences and product types.
